# Recursively copying registry subtree where some subkey names contain slashes

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm having trouble using PowerShell to copy registry subtrees as some keys contain slashes (for example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages\Language Services\C/C++`)

```
PS > Copy-Item -recurse HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages HKCU:\ZZZ

Copy-Item : The registry key at the specified path does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -recurse HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages HKCU:\So ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (HKEY_CURRENT_US...odeExpansions\C:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : The registry key at the specified path does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -recurse HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages HKCU:\So ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (HKEY_CURRENT_US...uage Services\C:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

How can I recursively copy such subtrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Powershell - it can't handle forward slash in registry path (applies to `get-childitem`, so I would expect it also to affect `copy-item`, `rename-item`, `move-item` etc).

https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=238838&SiteID=99

And still there in latest powershell (v4.0).

You could however use powershell to run the Reg DOS command:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742057.aspx

```
reg.exe copy HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages HKCU:\ZZZ /s
```

Comment: I've tried `-literalpath`, but it gives the same errors. Sadly, the `-whatif` is rather useless for registry. It outputs `What if: Performing the operation "Copy Key" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Languages\ Destination: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ZZZ".` and then prints two errors about "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ZZZ" not existing.

Comment: I've updated my answer - seems it's a known and as yet unresolved issue with Powershell where registry paths have a forward slash in them.

Comment: In Powershell 5.1 the issue apparently still persists.